# How can I represent something good for user and bad for the business in a graphical way?

Tags: gui-design, interface, marketing

I have this interface which is a [stepper](https://dribbble.com/tags/stepper) that asks user for several medical conditions. Based on the results, we have 2 final options:

- **if result are bad**, user will benefit from the business' service
- **if result are good**, user won't need the services

There is no complication at all in the algorithm, it's quite straightforward

However, all screens for each step have graphics: mostly illustrations, but also some infographics. They add [delight](https://medium.com/@101/stop-pushing-features-and-start-delight-users-ef639194c199), information and hopefully will increase engagement -still untested, but I'm quite sure it will-.

The problem comes with the final screen when results are good. Client's marketing department gave us the text, which starts as follows:

> Thank you for your interest in XXXXXXXXX. Based on what you have told
>   us, our program doesn’t seem appropriate for your condition at this
>   time. (....)

Now, this is good news for the user *or maybe bad: condition could be so bad user requires really expensive treatment, we recommend checking with a doctor at the bottom of the marketing messaging*, but bad news for the business.

So my problem is: how can I conceptually represent something that is good for user (or maybe really bad!) and bad for the business without looking phony. I mean: **business might be legitimally happy that the user is in good health, but it can't be happy about losing business.**

My approach right now is to end this screen with some abstract shapes, but I would like to know if there's some kind of concept we can illustrate in order to keep the whole interface consistent

## EDIT

Here's the sample of the first 2 screens. Sorry for the huge ugly logo, I just did a quick edit so I can show it
[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting question...Do you have any mockups so far, with all of your text in context of this final screens? It seems the copywriting here is crucial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only possible solution to this question is to sit down with your group of designers (if you have one) and make a brainstorming.
There are several things involved, what can help is a relative order. According to what's explained in the question, there are five different "states":

[image]

And three possible combinations:

[image]

Finding a solution for 1, 2, 3, X, Y can help to fix A - B and C

Well, I'm not in your design team and I have not the company marketing directives. On interfaces with graphics, animations have always a very positive effect, beyond the result obtained. Some ideas:

[image: Status A]

---

[image: Status B]

---

[image: Status C]

---

*Original animation from [gifer.com](https://i.gifer.com/TssN.gif)*

Comment: Associating the brand with a frown is neither helpful nor necessary (for either the user or the brand).

Comment: I know, as I said in the answer, i'm not the company GD. I just put the symbol to show the good or bad business situation, looking for a better icon or graphic that represents it is not a job that I should do.

Comment: Amazing answer. While the formula isn't exact (my poor explanation), it shows the approach to tackle the right choice and I already have some ideas to brainstorm on Monday, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if i'm missing something but why do you even need to convey anything bad for business to the user? If the user is in good health and does not need your business' services - then i would change the message to something like;

"Thanks for your interest, but it seems you're fighting fit right now! Would you like us to contact you in a [x} months for a check-up?"

I'd say this way the user leaves happy they are in good health, and you don't completely lose their interest/potential custom.

P.S. As an aside, I find messages like the one you're conveying after filling out a form to say "You don't meet our standards" with no feedback to be frustrating, so perhaps outline why they don't meet your criteria as well (but that may just be me?)

Comment: I agree with you, and as a matter of fact we trasmitted something along those lines. Sadly we have no permission to change the content, because it comes from their marketing department, we can only change the visual style

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are assessing (medical diagnoses?) and what the product is (phramaceuticals?), there may be regulations or guidelines restricting specifically what you may claim or recommend.

**Some options to consider:**

- Focus on the user. You can use a health indicator to give an overall assessment. You can use check marks and exes to draw attention to specific problem areas.
- Educate users about their condition. What are they doing right? What can they improve?
- Include non-product-related advice, such as recommended dietary or exercise changes.
- If the product *may* be helpful, suggest it. If the product won't be helpful, don't mention it.
- Message brought to you by... This may improve public awareness and opinion of the parent company.